# How to control replication?

Tags: active-directory, replication

I want to disable **replication** of the user's *first name* attribute. That is Whenever I change its value, it should not be *replicated*. How can I do that?

Comment: Why? Active-Directory is a database that should be accurately reflected on querying the database. If you spell out what the final goal is maybe there is another alternative that makes more sense.

Comment: No final goals. I just want to know whether we can choose any attributes not to be replicated. Like lastlogon, badpassword count, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, [is sort of...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248717) You can edit what gets replicated to the Global Catalog.

I can see no reason why this would be a good practice right now though. Active-Directory as a database should be the source of verifying identities between locations, not for storing mismatched data. If you want nick names, then use nicknames in a standard way that can be verified. If you want less visible attributes, then use hidden Extension attributes.

Active-Directory should be one of the places you know the data is correct and uniform.